# Does the alternating p-series converge conditionally for $p\leq0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

I'm aware that the alternating p-series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n1/n^p$ converges absolutely for $p>1$ and conditionally for $0<p\leq1$, and these are fairly straightforward to prove. But what about $p\leq0$, where the alternating series test fails?

I know that the series cannot be absolutely convergent, since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|(-1)^n1/n^p|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^p$ and this is just a p-series with $p\leq0$ which diverges.

Comment: For a series to converge, its term *must* tend to zero.

Comment: why did I not consider that... thanks! So the series has to diverge.

Comment: No because the term $a_n$ does not converge to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Metamorphy already answered your question. But adding more details: the answers is no because the terms of your series are
$$a_n=(-1)^nn^p$$
with $p\ge0$ and $a_n$ does not converges to $0$. This implies that your series diverges.